# SMTP server service?

Tags: smtp

I'm looking for a good SMTP host. I need to be able to:

1. Send as much as 25000 emails per day.
2. Connect to the smtp server from ONLY one IP

Basically, my host has a 500 email per hour limit. And the website I'm working on sends notifications for everything from changing your details, to adding details etc. Also, the site has a mass mail feature for "contacts". So, if you have 500 contacts and you wish to mail all of them, that means all the mails are sent in one go. Now imagine if the site has 500 users. Do you see how quickly my limit of mails "explode". As a solution, instead of getting a dedicated server, I figured I could just pay someone to host the SMTP serve.

Any advice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[SMTP.com](http://www.smtp.com/corporate.html)

Their corporate plans allow anything from 20,000 emails/hr to 100,000 emails/hr.

Comment: As much as I love your wit and humor, maybe just tone it down a tad, however +1 for the option :)

Comment: Aye aye, cap'n! :)

Comment: Not exactly the most affordable solution. I opted for getting a dedicated server and just doing everything myself. Thanks tho.

Comment: No worries, unfortunately high-speed high-volume SMTP servers are priced about there - and SMTP.com has a really good rep. Good luck in getting the right dedicated server hosting provider!

Answer (score 1):

[MailEnable](http://www.mailenable.com/) can handle a pretty huge volume of traffic and is highly configurable. Highly recommended.

Comment: I think I may have been unclear. I am not looking for software. I'm looking for a company that already provides this as a service. I.e. I just want a username, password and an adress such as smtp.someCoolHost.com.

Comment: Ah. It seems they do offer this. Busy finding out prices. :-)

Comment: I take it back. This is only software.